# Unit Tests, STAssertThrows and NSExceptions

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unit-testing, nsexception

I'm new with Unit Test and I've got question about it.

In my source code I have subclassed `NSMutableArray`. `NSMutableArray` must have implemented primitive `NSMutableArray` and `NSArray` methods. These methods in some case throws `NSExceptions` like `NSRangeExceptions`.

The question is: "When I make unit tests for this primitive methods should I write case for `NSExceptions`?

Example:

```
//array with 3 objects
STAssertThrows([array insertObject:object atIndex:8], @"");
```

1. Is this correct?
2. Is this neccesary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases to consider: Asserting that an exception will be thrown, and asserting that an exception will not be thrown.

The latter is not necessary, but can still be a good idea. It's an opportunity to provide a more explicit description in the assertion message of what you were expecting to happen, or not to happen. But, you can skip `STAssertNoThrow` and the exception will still fail the test.

If you *want* the exception to happen, then you will need to assert that, like you did in the code in the question. You should provide a meaningful assertion message, though, rather than the empty string.

Comment: Thank you. I don't want this exception (`NSExceptionRange`) in my code. This is programmer error, so, when it's happend, then app will crash. So this is normal behaviour of `insertObject` method. When index is out of range, then crash. So the questions are: (1)Is this case in Unit Tests neccesary? (2) Should I use STAssertThrows only when I have to catch exceptions and then do something with it?

Comment: @TomaszSzulc: (1) Yes, it's worth testing that your methods handle nonsense, such as out-of-range inputs, as well as they handle valid inputs. (2) You should use `STAssertThrows` when a particular exception is the correct result of an expression. That function will catch the exception and fail the test for you; you don't need to do anything beyond that.